# Do you have to normalize the data for a neural net if it is already scaled?

Tags: neural-network, weka, normalization, training-data, perceptron

I'm currently trying to preprocess my training data ready for a multi-layered perceptron. The data I downloaded consists of 20,000 instances and 16 attributes, all of which are coordinate values of pixels as part of letter recognition. The data itself has already been scaled from its original form into values between 0 - 15 before being published.

However since it's already been scaled, is it still necessary to perform normalization on it? I've tried to read around and look at previous examples but have come up with conflicting points. In some papers, it has stated that scaling is a form of normalization, where as others have said that normalization would be bringing that values to a range of 0-1.

Since I'm using WEKA I've attempted their normalize filter during a pre-processing stage and it caused the accuracy to decrease by around 2% which makes me think it could be unnecessary. But again, I've read that it may only have a positive effect later in training.

So my question is:

What is the difference between scaling to a range such as 0 - 15 and normalizing it? Should I still normalize it on top of this scaling thats already done?

Answer (score 1):

In your case you do not need to. Normalizing data is done so that an attribute with a different scale will not decide outcome of distance operations, ultimately decide clustering or classification results.

An example you have two attributes weight and income. Weight will be 10 and 200kg at most. While  income can be 10,000$ and 20,000,000$. But most of the people's income will be 10,000 and 120,000, while above this values will be outliers. If you do not normalize your data before using Multi Layer Perceptron, outcome of your neural network will be decided by these outliers.

In your case this situation is already mitigated due to your scaling therefore you do not need normalizing.